# DJango: how to correctly use Django authentification?

Tags: django, authentication

I've use a tutorial to implement authentification (app registration) and it works but I do not understand well

I have declare registration url in the django project

**myproject/urls.py**

`path('registration/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),`

So authentification use default LoginViews, LogoutViews...

I have also declare (below) but these urls are not used as even if I suppress these urls autentifications still works...

what is the corect way of authentification?

**registration/views.py**

````
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


app_name='registration'
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
]```
````

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly isn't working with the code you're showing? Did you remove `path('registration', ...)` from your main project urls if you're trying to override them? Did you `include()` your own _registration/urls.py_ instead?

Comment: the code works but... First, I would like confirmation that my 2 path are useless...

Comment: an d yes, I would like to understand how I can override views and template without breaking all authentification...

Comment: should I 'simply' copy/paste site-packages\django\contrib\auth urls.py and views.py in my app and modify them as I need? don't thikn so but...

Comment: Currently you're not showing any code that includes the urls you defined in registration/views.py. If you don't include them they are useless. But you need to understand how urls work, it works from top to bottom. So if you first say that `/registration/` should be going to django.contrib.auth.urls, then anything you define after that starting with `/registration` is ignored. You need to include in the right order, that's all.

Comment: I have no code for views and urls because I think that site-packages\django\contrib\auth\urls.py and site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py are include via this line: ```path('registration/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define the urls in the correct order. Django reads the routes from top to bottom and the first match is taken.

If for example you only want to override the login view, you can do this in your project's urls.py:

```
path('registration/login/', my_views.login, name="login"),
path('registration/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

If you want to override more views, I'd rather redefine all the urls from django.contrib.auth.urls in your **registration/urls.py**. In that case, do this:

```
# project urls.py
from registration import urls as registration_urls
path('registration', include(registration_urls)),

# registration/urls.py
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views as my_views

# ...
path('login', my_views.login, name="login"),
path('logout', my_views.logout, name="logout"),
# ...
path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
path('password_change/done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),

path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
# ...
```

Comment: OK, but I want to 'add' behavior to my login for example declare and set session variable or prevent login template to be displayed if user is already logged in (redirect_authenticated_user)...

Comment: so How I override login view to do that?

Comment: Look at the django one and change what you need to change. Easiest is to subclass the class-based view LoginView so you inherit the default functionality and only add what you need. But if you prefer to use a function based view then you’ll have to copy&paste and change it.

Comment: thanks dirkgroten but what do you mean by 'look at django one and change what you need to change'... how should I subclass the class-based view?

Comment: `LoginView` is just a regular python class so you can subclass it like any python class. Then you can override its methods to change behavior, calling `super()` to reuse the parent class’s behavior. If you don’t know what I’m talking about you should do some more python learning first, about classes and inheritance.

Comment: When I said “look at the django one” I meant literally opening the file django.contrib.auth.views.py and looking at the code to figure out what and where you need to change behavior.

Comment: OK, thanks dirkgroten, now it is clear. You are right I must learn more about inheritance in Python (I am newbie in Python 4 months)